# How to fix overcurrent fault pin triggering stepper motor driver to stop? Or how to reduce current spikes?

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I am using two [DRV8825](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8825.pdf#page=18) stepper motor drivers. They each control a [NEMA23](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/nema-23-stepper-motor-1-85nm-256-9oz-in-with-9mm-shaft-for-nmrv30-worm-gear-speed-reducer-23hs30-2804s-rv) with a [50:1 gear box](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/50-1-worm-gearbox-nmrv30-worm-gear-speed-reducer-9mm-input-shaft-diameter-nmrv30-g50-d9).

VREF is connected to the DAC of an [ESP32](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/espressif-systems/ESP32-DEVKITC-32D/9356990) ([datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf)). This is so I can control the torque. (I have a hard stop for each motor. These are used with homing routine using reduced torque.)

Eventually, sometimes less than a minute and sometimes more than five minutes, one motors stops and the nFault pin on that diver goes to zero volts. Normally, they are at 0.18-0.25 V (which is still logic low).

So I supplied each nFault with 3v3. The problem is not overtemperature. There is a gigantic heat sink. I even put a fan on it and measured the temperature. It's around 30 C (not more than 31 C).

That means the nFault is triggering due to over-current. So I modified the program to reset nFault to HIGH every few cycles:

```
  if (theta >= 2 * PI)
  {
    completedCircles++;

    if (completedCircles >= 9)
    {
      digitalWrite(14, LOW);
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      completedCircles = 0;  // Reset counter
    }

    theta = 0;  // Reset theta for the next circle
  }
```

I guess this is similar to toggling the nReset pin. I would rather not have to force reset the driver ICs. Instead, what are some things that can be done to reduce intermittent current spikes?

I don't know what else it could be.

[image]

Comment: This schematic does not show connectivity very well: net labels are barely readable, and they provide no indication of where the same labels might appear elsewhere. Please draw with neatly arranged wires. What are the GTs? That is not a familiar designator; with no other labels, readers do not know what they are or how they should connect. Finally, please show PCB layout, preferably with photos showing connections, enclosure, grounding, etc.

Comment: Updated schematic, but it is really just an unnecessary extra. Previous versions of the PCB worked. For this version, the main difference is connecting one ESP32's DAC to the VREFs. I am not allowed to show the footprint.

Comment: Have you probed any signals with a scope yet?

Comment: I have yes. It's noisy. So I put on a ground planes for the most current PCB. (If I was working on this at home, I would just try the TMC2209 instead of the DRV8825 driver.)

Comment: The ESP32's DAC outputs may be affected by noise or power supply fluctuations. So I will try implementing some sort of filtering or buffering. Although, all ESP32 output pins are limited to 12mA (maximum). There might be something there.